# CSC Roslyn compiler - write errors to STDERR

Tags: roslyn, csc

By default the CSC compiler writes all output to STDOUT. Is there a compiler option that can redirect the errors to STDERR?

I need this functionality to write all of the errors to a file. Another option would be to manually parse the output for errors with regex; however there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: If you want to parse the errors, you should use the Roslyn APIs directly, which will give you actual error objects instead of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; all output always goes to `Console.Out`.

You can see this in the [source](http://source.roslyn.io/#csc/Csc.cs,35).

If you want to, you can send a pull request to change this.

---

You can also pass the [`/errorlog` option](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Desktop/CommandLine/CommandLineParser.cs,899) to write errors to a file.

Comment: The latest Visual Studio 2015 CTP doesn't have this option (version 1.0.0.50128):
error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '/errorlog:error.log'

Comment: @IlyaSuzdalnitski: You're right; you need a newer build.  https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/6b92b1820c6dcf1198366e56db600e768bccc227